# Creating a signed JWT to replace a Bearer token

Tags: jwt, bearer-token

I use an API which accepts a Bearer token for authorisation.

For testing, I've been told that I need to generate a signed JWT, but I don't know how to do this.

To acquire a Bearer token I am using an API which returns a message of this form:

```
{
    "access_token": "<long string>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    <other fields>
}
```

Is this message an unsigned\unencoded JWT? (From [this page](https://jwt.io/introduction) I assume not.)

Given that I need to pass a signed JWT to the API endpoint, how would I...

1. Create the JWT if I am in possession of a Bearer token, list of claims, etc?
2. Pass the signed JWT to the API endpoint instead of the Bearer token?

Comment: It's not really clear what you need. It looks like you already get a token (access_token), so why don't you use this? Is this access token maybe a JWT? Does it begin with eyJ... and consists of 3 strings separated by `.`?

Comment: The JSON response I’ve posted is what I get back. Is that a signed JWT? I assume it isn’t. What I need is a way to turn it into a signed JWT.

Comment: no, that's just a typical response containing a token. What I asked above is: how does the `<long string>` in this response look like? Is it maybe already the JWT you need?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, it is just a random string. There are no ‘.’ for example. It is not 3-part.

Comment: ok, so it's not a JWT. Besides that, your question does not contain nearly enough information to write a helpful answer. Generally there are tons of examples for most languages. On https://jwt.io there's a list of libs for many languages and on the github repos you can usually find examples. But that would just tell you how the general coding works. What you also would need to know is: which claims are required (eg. issuer (iss), audience (aud) and which values are expected by the API. Which signature algorithm should be used and which keys should be used. The API owner should tell you that.